# Remove quotes from JSON and replace curly brackets with square brackets

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, flot

I am trying to create an array of data for use with a [FLOT](http://www.flotcharts.org/) chart.  I am using this CodeIgniter code to generate the array:

```
function ajaxmuniChart1c(){
$muni = $this->input->POST('muni');
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT SaleYear AS Y, NewSaleType AS T, count(*) AS C, format((sum(SalePrice) / sum(Quantity1)),0) AS R FROM tblsales WHERE  tblsales.SaleYear > 2007 AND tblsales.Quantity1 > 2000 AND (tblsales.NewSaleType = 'Industrial') AND tblsales.Municipality = '".$muni."' GROUP BY T,Y ORDER BY T,Y");
$json_Array    = array();
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row){
    $JsonArray[] = array( floatval($row['Y']) => floatval($row['R']) );
}
$labeledArray = array( 
    "label" => "Average Sale Price per SF",
    "data" => $JsonArray
);
echo json_encode($labeledArray);
exit;
}
```

The problem with this code is that the resulting JSON object cannot be plotted because the "values" are in fact strings.  Here is the problematic JSON output:

```
 {"label":"Average Price","data":[{"2008":96},{"2009":74},{"2010":73},{"2011":96},{"2012":124},{"2013":104}]}
```

There are three problems with this JSON:

1. Need square brackets instead of curly brackets; and
2. Need to use commas to separate the key->value pair instead of full-colon; and
3. Quotes need to be removed so that the string "2008" becomes the value 2008.

Here is the way the JSON output needs to be formatted:

```
 ["label":"Average Price","data":[[2008,96],[2009,74],[2010,73],[2011,96],[2012,124],[2013,104]]]
```

What is the best way to clean-up this JSON object?  Should I do it on the server side with the CodeIgniter code?  Or should I do it on the client side in javascript after the JSON object has been made?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you generate that JSON, you can change its source.

```
$JsonArray[] = array( floatval($row['Y']) => floatval($row['R']) );
```

-->

```
$JsonArray[] = array( floatval($row['Y']), floatval($row['R']) );
```

(This changes arrays like `{"2008": 80}` to `[2008, 80]`.)

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks Brian.  You made my weekend!